# Automate Image annotation procedure for tf model training

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, annotations, computer-vision, training-data

I have about 50000 above data set for training a model. I already have a self-trained mobilenet model which was trained with 10000 images and it has some error cases in some scenarios. So I am planning for annotating more data set. But the annotation procedure takes much time. Can anybody suggest a method or tool for automating/semi-automate the annotation procedure? (Currently using labelImg tool for annotation(PASCAL VOC)).

Comment: check out Computer Vision Annotation Tool https://github.com/opencv/cvat

Comment: Thanks. Is this offline?